# Is there a setting or a way to show a breakdown of the total column for a Matrix Visual (see example)?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Currently, my matrix visual looks like this with the 2 attributes in the column (an organization and the transaction type) [Matrix Visual currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0pWy.png)

I would ideally like the Total column to also be split by "BUY", "SEL", "DRIP". Is this a setting that I'm just not finding? I had a look through the total settings but couldn't find it.

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I breakdown my Totals in my Power BI Matrix visual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862754/how-do-i-breakdown-my-totals-in-my-power-bi-matrix-visual)