# How do I breakdown my Totals in my Power BI Matrix visual?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to breakdown the Total columns by "BUY", "SEL" and "DRIP" just like the other columns in the screenshot ([Matrix Visual in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhPSB.png)

I've tried going through the Matrix visual settings and searching for "total", playing around with as much as I could, but there doesn't seem to be an option for this specific feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a setting for this.

To include multiple columns for the Total, you will need to add multiple values in the Matrix `Values well`.
[image]

**Example 1**:
Three measures created (one for each) and these added to the `Values well`.
[image]
The drawback is you won't get sub-column total.

**Example 2**:
As before, and with a fourth measure for the "sub-total", also added to the `Values well`.
[image]
The drawback here is that the "sub-total" (`mTot`) isn't really a sub-total in the Matrix and won't be formatted as such (ie in bold). However, we can apply font and background colour to it.

Example of the measures used:

```
mB = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]), 'Table'[Attribute] = "B")

mD = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]), 'Table'[Attribute] = "D")

mS = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]), 'Table'[Attribute] = "S")

mTot = [mB] + [mD] + [mS]
```